# Pandas Faster Way for One Hot Encoding vs pd.get_dummies

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I need to one hot encode categorical variables on my pandas data frame.

My dataset is really big with **over 2000 productIDs** to be one hot encoded.

I tried pd.get_dummies and it always crashes.

I have also tried scikit-learn's OneHotEncoder which also crashes! (it works fine with a smaller subset of dataframe)

What other methods are there? What is the most efficient way to one hot encode categorical variables for very big data set?

My data frame:

```
Month   User    ProductID
1       A       ProdA
3       A       ProdB
11      A       ProdC
12      A       ProdD
```

Required output:

```
Month   User    ProdA  ProdB  ProdC  ProdD
1       A       1      0      0      0
3       A       0      1      0      0
11      A       0      0      1      0
12      A       0      0      0      1
```

Comment: Given the number of levels in your categorical data, you might look into something like [Catboost](https://catboost.ai/) which is built to handle categorical variables without encoding

Comment: Have you looked into using keras or some other ML lib? keras has a function [to_categorical](https://keras.io/utils/#to_categorical) that might work.

Comment: @ayhan I have also tried scikit-learn's OneHotEncoder which also crashes! (it works fine with a smaller subset of dataframe)

Comment: That's really surprising. How many rows does your dataframe have? Can you perform basic operations over the whole thing? (like mapping +1 to a numerical field, etc). If you want to parallelize operations on a cluster of computers, you can look into [koalas](https://github.com/databricks/koalas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My dataset is really big with over 2000 productIDs and million of user rows.

This will result in a huge dataset. Presumably it's crashing because of memory.

Perhaps you should consider alternatives to full one-hot encoding.

One way is to create dummies of the top categories, and "other" for the rest.

```
tops = df.ProductID.value_counts().head(10)
```

will give you the top product ids. You can then use

```
df.ProductID[~df.ProductID.isin(tops)] = 'other'
```

and create dummies out of that.

If you have a response variable, you might alternatively use [mean encoding](https://towardsdatascience.com/why-you-should-try-mean-encoding-17057262cd0).

Comment: sounds like a very good idea! i will give it a try, should work.

Answer (score 0):

For a feature with so many different possible values, one-hot encoding may not be the best option.

I suggest using Target Encoding (https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/).  Unlike one-hot encoding, which will create k columns for k unique values of the feature, target encoding transforms the one feature into one column.